# Google HTTP/REST OAuth: authorisation code request has state for db user, access token request has none

Tags: javascript, php, http, google-calendar-api, google-oauth

I am using the OAuth server flow for Google.
It starts with the user clicking a link that runs javascript to open a popup with the following request in the URI which is all working great:

```
var endpoint = "https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth";
        endpoint = endpoint + "?scope="+encodeURIComponent(googlecalendar.SCOPES);
        endpoint = endpoint + "&redirect_uri="+encodeURIComponent("https://myserver/google/");
        endpoint = endpoint + "&response_type=code";
        endpoint = endpoint + "&access_type=offline";
        endpoint = endpoint + "&approval_prompt=force";
        endpoint = endpoint + "&client_id="+encodeURIComponent(googlecalendar.CLIENT_ID);
        endpoint = endpoint + "&state="+encodeURIComponent(googlecalendar.USER_ID);
```

On the server side, I get the state which contains the user_id for my DB and the authorisation code.
Now I want to exchange the authorisation code for access token (and renew token). This will be a HTTP request with a redirect URI, no state parameter is included.

The problem is that when I get those, I will need to store them against a user in my DB, but I don't have any way to check which user the callback is for.

The best I was able to come up with is using the token to query the google user's identity it belongs to but this still won't help me to find the user in the DB.

Can anyone help me with this flow? There must be some way to do. I don't want to use client libraries because later when I need to create watchers the PHP client library does not include this for the calendar API.

Comment: If there was some way to use authorization code to find the google user then I could link it to my db using the state but after exchanging the code for tokens I no longer have a way to link the db user to the renew token. It seems like I will have to use sessions to keep a state.

Comment: I cannot see the problem with this. When you recieve the authorisation code parameter (and the state parameter with in userID) at the provided return URL (https://myserver/google/), you have to make the token request immediately within the same request (i guess), because the authorisation token is only valid for a few seconds. So you have your needed userID aviabele, right?

Comment: The problem is that when I have to exchange it, I make a new request with the code and a redirect uri. When it comes back to this other redirect uri I won't know which user it is for.

Comment: The only solution I can come up with is to do it on my application server and to use the session to keep track of the user. I wanted to do it all on my api server that will be watching for push notifications which has no session state. Since I will be doing an app with the same functionality, this will make things very tricky later on. If there is a solution that doesn't involve using a session then that will be ideal.

Comment: But the call to the exchange URL (to get the (refresh)token), isn't redirected anymore. Its just a post request (using CURL for example). The redirect URL you have to post is just for google to verify the request.

Comment: Only the authorisation request (the first one) will be redirected

Comment: Ok, I didn't realise that. I must look into it more. If that's the case then my problem is solved! Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Short Answer

Despite the presence of a redirect parameter, the access token will generate a standard 200 response, not a 301 redirect. Depending on how you issue and handle the request/response, you can preserve your state.

#### More Detailed Answer

According to [section 4.1.4](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749#section-4.1.4) of the OAuth 2.0 spec document (RFC 6749), the response to an Access Token Request should be an "HTTP/1.1 200 OK".

In other words, the server will not perform a redirect, meaning you can issue a request and process the response in the same scope (either in the client or server, whatever your situation), so your database user ID need only be in local memory.

This is different from the Authorization Request, which is supposed to result in an "HTTP/1.1 302 Found" (redirect). See [section 4.1.2](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749#section-4.1.2).

So why is the `redirect_uri` parameter required?

According to [section 4.1.3](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749#section-4.1.3), the server must:

- *ensure that the "redirect_uri" parameter is present if the "redirect_uri" parameter was included in the initial authorization request as described in Section 4.1.1, and if included ensure that their values are identical.*

In other words, the `redirect_uri` acts as a sort of secret or password which the server must use to verify the access token request. If the client fails to provide a `redirect_uri` parameter, or the parameter value is different from the original request, then the server must reject the access token request.